# Which disk is in which hard drive bay

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have a Dell Poweredge R710 with 6 drive bays (and 6 hard drives). There is a DELL PERC H700 raid controller card in the system. I mirrored all of the drives so they appear as 3 separate disks.

I'm seeing messages like this in event viewer:

```
The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk3\DR7.
The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk3\DR6
```

The number at the end changes, but always as Harddisk3, which I am certain is the E: drive. Disks are cheap, so I plan on removing both drives that represent the E drive.

My primary question is, How can I tell which 2 drives, in which 2 drive bays, represent the E drive?

I forgot to mention that I am running Windows Server 2016.

Comment: What do the status LEDs show?

Comment: @shodanshok It's blue and simply shows the service tag number.

Comment: The physical disk's status LED (the one integrated into the disk tray itself) should be green/amber/red and surely does not show any service tags. Can you double-check the right LED?

Comment: @shodanshok Sorry. I misunderstood. They are all Green.

Comment: If LEDs are green, so the issue is not on the physical disk. You should use OpenManage or iDRAC to access the controller's log.

Answer (score 0):

The disks shown by your OS are in the order reported by the RAID controller - most likely the order in which you've defined them.

You'll need to check the PERC configuration on which disk is where and which one reported errors. You can use PERCCLI in Windows, the BIOS utility, or the Open Manage utility.

While you're at it you might want to properly document your RAID setup.